# Adding VTL to AWS API Gateway Python CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

How do i put VTL like the code below that includes pound signs, for loops and if statements into AWS Python CDK apigateway construct like the code further below

```
#set($data = $input.path('$'))
#set($machinez = $input.path('$.Machines'))
{
  "Payload":[
    #foreach($reading in $data.Payload)
      {
        "CustomerID": "$data.CustomerID",
        "MachineID":"$reading.MachineID",
        "Make": #foreach($mac in $machinez)#if($reading.MachineID == $mac.MachineID)"$mac.Make"#else#end#end,
        "Time":"reading.Time"
      }
      #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  ]
}
```

```
api_gateway_to_dynamo_integration = apigateway.AwsIntegration(
            service="dynamodb",
            action="PutItem",
            options=apigateway.IntegrationOptions(
                request_templates={
                    "application/json": json.dumps({
                        "TableName": self.my_table.table_name,
                        "Item": {
                            self.MY_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY: {
                                "S": "$input.path('$.Id')"
                            },
                        }
                    })
                }
            ),          
        )
```